# Erro retorna ao tentar iniciar alguns threads em uma lista

Tags: c#, multithreading

Preciso criar uma função para meu programa, que quando o usuário estiver apertar o `NUMPAD_8`, ele desligue todos os `thread`, e caso ele aperte de novo, ele os liga novamente.

Como eu estou criando a lista de threads:

```
public static List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

public static void addThreads()
{
    threads.Add(new Thread());
    threads.Add(new Thread());
    threads.Add(new Thread());
    threads.Add(new Thread());
    threads.Add(new Thread());
    threads.Add(new Thread());
    threads.Add(new Thread());
    //Só deixei em branco o Thread() para ilustrar melhor o problema,
    //em meu programa eles estão preenchidos todos corretamente.
}
```

Como eu estou iniciando os threads:

```
Vars.addThreads();
foreach (Thread t in Vars.threads)
{
    t.Start();
}
```

Como eu tentei:

```
if (Gambiarras.ChecarPressionando(0x68))
{
    foreach (Thread t in Vars.threads)
    {
        if (t.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
            t.Abort();
        else
            t.Start();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

O `.Abort()` até funciona bem, mas o `.Start()` me retorna o seguinte erro:

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'O thread está em execução ou foi encerrado. Não pode ser reiniciado.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro acontece porque uma Thread não pode ser reiniciada.

Deve chamar novamente o método `addThreads()` para elas serem recriadas.

Acrescente ao método

```
threads.Clear();
```

para que a lista seja limpa.

Terá de alterar a lógica dentro do `if` pois isso não pode ser feito no `else`.

Tenha em conta que:

- Usar `Abort()` é mau, ver [How To Stop a Thread in .NET](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation)
- Considere usar [Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) em vez de Thread.

Comment: Ao invés de usar `foreach` e `if`, teria como eu fazer isso com o `.forEach.Where`? Reconheço que isso está fora do escopo da pergunta, mas, pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Não porque não "existe" `ForEach.Where`. `ForEach` retorna `void`. Quanto muito `Where.ToList.ForEach`.